# How to loop through userform until selection is made or exit is hit?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a userform where customers need to make a selection because the subsequent code cannot work without input.

I check if a selection was made.
If no selection was made, I would like to
(i) display an error message and
(ii) loop through this sequence until a selection is made or exit is hit (the exit-button is another option in the userform apart from "ok").

The problem is that the loop sequence constantly displays the message box. The user is not able to get back to the form and make a re-selection.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton_weiter_Click()
    'check if selection made
    Do While True
    If ComboBox_Kunde.Value = "" Or ComboBox_Lager.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Your selection is incomplete." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
            & "Please make a selection or exit the form.", vbCritical
    End If
    Loop
    
    'selection
    Dim WB As Workbook: Set WB = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim WS As Worksheet: Set WS = WB.Sheets("directory")
    Dim lager As Range: Set lager = WS.Range("lager")
    
    lager.Value = ComboBox_Lager.Value
    
    UserForm_Selection.Hide
    Unload UserForm_Selection
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, which OP indicated was 'perfect' (AKA working):

> You could use `Exit Sub` if the condition is not met.
>
> - [braX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8422953/brax) - [2021-05-20 7:17:04Z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67615640/how-to-loop-through-userform-until-selection-is-made-or-exit-is-hit#comment119514079_67615640)